# Nextjs light mode glitching on macbook pro m3

Tags: reactjs, macos, debugging, next.js

I am running a fresh install of nextjs with the latest version as of feb 7 2024, on node 20.11.0 Lts. no type script, no tailwind, yes to app router.

Using a 2023 macbook pro m3 using the light mode appearance in the macbook settings, as soon as I create a blank page in react it gives me this...
[light mode bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VUAt.png)
but as soon as I switch my macbook theme to dark mode...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8VdH.png)
it works just fine.
Is this a mac glitch? is there a setting I need to change in nextjs?
note: I have not changed a single thing just added a new folder in my app folder called awesome and a page.js inside there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em5gj.png)

Tried another fresh install with and without typescript, with and without tailwind, page seems to only be normal with the dark mode applied in the mac settings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.